# Image not updating django

Tags: django

In my edit.html I have a form where the user can edit information on a trainee. The user can add many trainees, edit them, delete them etc. Everything works fine there except the image. The imagefield of form appears in a very messy state. Also it does not update when I select a new image. Here is my code. I have cut down my code to make it more readable

models.py

```
class Trainee(models.Model):  
TraineePic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank= True, upload_to="traineeImg/")
Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Meta():
    db_table = "Trainee"
```

forms.py

```
class TraineeForm(forms.ModelForm):
TraineePic = forms.ImageField(label="Image :", required=False)
Name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'col-sm-4'}), label='Name :')

class Meta():
    model = Trainee
    fields = ("Name","TraineePic",)
```

views.py

```
class UpdateTrainee(UpdateView):
model = Trainee
template_name = 'MyTestApp/edit.html'
form_class = TraineeForm
success_url = reverse_lazy('show')
```

edit.html

```
{% extends "MyTestApp/base.html" %}
{% block body_block %}
{% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/bootstrap.min.css'%}" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
    ul#id_Gender li{
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>
<body>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <h2> Edit Trainee </h2>
    <form method="post" class="form-group" type="multipart/form-data" data-ajax="false">
        {%csrf_token%}
        {{form.errors}}

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">{{ form.TraineePic.label }}</label>
            {{form.TraineePic}}

        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">{{ form.Name.label }}</label>
            {{ form.Name }}

        </div>


       
        <input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-dark">
    </form>
</div>
</body>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is how the **form.TraineePic** looks like:
[image]

I also tried adding FileInput like this     *TraineePic = forms.ImageField(label="Image :", required=False,widget=forms.FileInput)*
But then I don't get any image. Any help would be appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Looks like there was a typo in my form in edit.html
I changed my form from

```
form method="post" class="form-group" type="multipart/form-data">
```

to

```
form method="post" class="form-group" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

And the image field in the form which looked very bad previously, I put it in a div with `style='display: inline-block'` so now it looks pretty ok.[image: Present]

Answer (score 0):

You must use #request.FILES to get image from frontend to backend and make it successfully save on database.

**In views.py**

```
 Example:
 Trainee_Pic= self.request.FILES.get('TraineePic')  # Use request.FILES
```

Comment: I changed my view and added this                                                                                       `def form_valid(self, form):  form.TraineePic = self.request.FILES.get('TraineePic')
        return super().form_valid(form)` Stil ldoes not work